# ExpandEnvironmentStringsA() String Subscript out of range

Tags: environment-variables

I have a Function which checks to see if IIS is installed and gets the installation path.

```
    int IsIISInstalled(string &pathname)
{
    DWORD returnvalue;
    long keyres = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Microsoft\\InetStp\\", 0, KEY_READ, &miva);
    if (keyres == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        char szBuffer[512];
        DWORD dwBufferSize = sizeof(szBuffer);
        ULONG nError;
        nError = RegQueryValueExA(miva, "InstallPath", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)szBuffer, &dwBufferSize);
        if (nError == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            char retBuffer[512];
            DWORD nsize = sizeof(retBuffer);
            returnvalue = ExpandEnvironmentStringsA(szBuffer, retBuffer, nsize);
            pathname = retBuffer;
            
        }

    }
    if (!pathname.empty())
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

When i attach to my executable and debug this there is a return value from ExpandEnvironmentStringsA
in retBuffer showing the installation path. returnvalue shows 28 as is the TCHARS that was put in the buffer. Once i step into the next line setting the string pathname to the retBuffer it fails giving me a string subscript out of range. I understand what that error means, i have done it plenty of times. What is odd to me is if i specify a new string var in the function:

```
string fakeresult;
```

and set fakeresult to retBuffer:

```
fakeresult = retBuffer;
```

just as i am in the code above it passes through just fine with no errors. I am calling the function with this code.

```
string iis_path, miva_path;
        int disable;
        char *full_path;
        //getMivaLocation(miva_path);
        bool good2go;
        int iisinstalled, empressaReturn, miaReturn;
        iisinstalled = IsIISInstalled(iis_path);
```

Does this have to do with the fact i am passing pathname by reference to the function?
If that is the case why?
How could i fix this to be able to return my data?
I am not a well educated c++ coder i am learning a lot of this as i go and have learned much from you guys. Hoping someone has an idea on this as i do not wish to spend much more time researching to no avail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After stepping into further i found that the pathname is being set as it should. It is immediately crashing on the next call to another functions so my debugging was incorrect. Now i have scoped further hopefully i can fix this. Also for my own note, the reason why it would not crash when i set fakestring instead of pathname was due to the fact i was passing pathname in the function call that is crashing. With no value it is not setting something out of its scope.